# What is Association Bonus?

Tags: discussion, support

Can anyone help me regarding association bonus?
**What is this association bonus anyway?**

Comment: See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 13):

StackExchange is a network of multiple Q & A sites. When you register for more than one site, you can do so using the same account ([I see that you have done that](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22893/chaitanya-moguluri)).

When any of your linked accounts reaches 200 [reputation points](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), all of the linked (or "associated") accounts receive a bonus of 100 reputation points - going from 1 to 100 grants [a handful of privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), including commenting and flagging.

It is kind of a "thank you, we now know that you know how to use the network, so we're granting you these privileges on all sites where you participate."